# Quais as ferramentas corretas para debugar código JavaScript para visualização no Browser?

Tags: javascript, debug

Recentemente, olhando uma pergunta aqui do Stackoverflow, observei o comentário de um usuário que dizia que o ***console.log*** e o ***alert*** não eram maneiras corretas para debugar códigos do JavaScript.

Essa questão me deixou pensativo, pois eu sempre utilizo o ***alert*** e o ***console.log*** para debugar códigos JavaScript e visualizá-los no navegador. (Também utilizo o echo, o var_dump e o print_r para o PHP).

Gostaria de saber se realmente essas essas opções, usadas por mim (no JS), são erradas, se existem outras mais indicadas ou se elas podem ser utilizadas normalmente. (Me refiro para utilização de debug no browser e que seja aplicado dentro do código JS, como acontece no caso do console.log).

Comment: Eu uso o Crome, pra mim atende muito bem! F12 -> Aba Network -> Control + P e pesquisa pelo arquivo!

Comment: @Marconi , eu utilizo essa ferramenta da 'Aba Network' para PHP.

Comment: Sempre uso pra fazer debug do meu js

Comment: Tem debugger em todos os navegadores

Comment: Eu uso vscode para codificar e próprio browser para depurar JS para depurar PHP uso o plugin XDebug no browser com PHP Debug no vscode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olá, acho que uma boa forma de debugar seu script seja da seguinte maneira...
Eu utilizo o google chrome, abrindo seu programa no browser, vá para a aba de desenvolvedor apertando F12 ou com o botão direito em inspecionar elemento... como nessa imagem :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**após isso na opção source você pode observar seu script e debugar colocando breakpoints da seguinte forma :**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como assim "colocar breakpoints" ? Em que parte do código, que vc postou como resposta, mostra isso ?

Comment: breakpoints você coloca na parte que você quer debugar, descobrir o valor da sua variável ou o descobrir porque o código não esta funcionando, é aquela parte azul marcada na linha na segunda imagem.

Comment: Obrigado, brother!

Answer (score 5):

Não tem problema usar o `console.log()` para debugar, mas é bem limitado. Eu por exemplo sempre usei (e uso quando bate a preguiça), mas pra alguma coisas fica mais fácil usar a aba `Sources` do Devtools do seu navegador.

Por exemplo, você pode usar breakpoints, em que seu código para no momento em que passar por ele e você tem acesso ao conteúdo das váriaveis, se entrou ou não em um `if`, quantas vezes passou por loop, etc. Fora muitas outras coisas que você vai aprendendo, que são muitas mesmo.

Também é possível usar o comando `debbuger;` no seu código, em que o mesmo para aonde foi colocando o `debbuger`.

Se você usa o Chrome, tem um tutorial de como debugar de vários jeitos: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: As duas respostas foram ótimas e parecidas, mas eu vou ficar com a do outro brother, leofalmeida. Somente por ele ter ilustrado com um exemplo. Mas dei um vote na sua também. Obrigado!

Comment: Sem problema, o importante é ter ajudado! :D